# Bootstrap card with title in semi transparent box over image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-cards

I want to create a bootstrap card where the title is in a semi transparent box over the image, while the rest of the card looks like regular bootstrap card.
This is my code so far:

```
<style>
.box{
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block; /* Make the width of box same as image */
}
.box .text{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;        
    text-align: center;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    top: 40%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
    background: rgba(178, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
    height: 10%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
        <div class="card img-fluid" style="width:500px">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="img/green.jpg" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
            <div class="card-img-overlay box">
                <h4 class="card-title text">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text">Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is how it looks: [image]

My issue with my code is that this red box containing the card title isn't responsive. It spans not just over the image, but over the entire card. How do I change it so that the red box is at the bottom of the image? I've already tried to change the css "top" and added a "bottom", but since the text is not over the image but over the whole card, it doesn't work.

I want the result to look like this:
[image]

The red box containing the card title should always stay on the bottom of the image, no matter the screen size.

*UPDATE*

This is how it looks like after including the code below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the .card-img-overlay element around the image and the title like this

```
<div class="card-img-overlay box">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="img/green.jpg" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
    <h4 class="card-title text">Title</h4>
</div>
```

And then give the title the following css

```
.box {
    position: relative;
}
.box .text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;     
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(178, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
    height: 10%;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this will give the desired result

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for this, the red box is now responsive and sticks to its place. I only have one issue left, the red box is overflowing the card. I tried `overflow: hidden;` but it isn't enough. Any idea why this is happening? I edited my question to include the picture of what I mean.

Comment: _Edit_ 

I found a work around, i changed the position to `position: relative;` and changed the `bottom` property to 28px. and it seemed to fix my problem. I probably isn't the best solution, but it works :D

Comment: Ah i see i forgot the left: 0; I would keep it absolute and give it left: 0; otherwise it is still gonna use the space underneath the title and you might have problems positioning elements underneath

Comment: No problem! glad i could help! could you accept my answer? :)